# mvc going from one view to another

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i would like to know how can we go from one view to another on a button click
here is what i did
my first view

```
@model mymvc.Models.TestModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "review";
}

                @Html.DropDownList("Dataid")
```

my second view

```
@model mymvc.Models.TestModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}



<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
</hgroup>

<section id="userform">

@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>User Entry Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Emailid)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Emailid)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Emailid)
            </li>


        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />

    </fieldset>

}
</section>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

my controller

```
 public class TestController : Controller
    {


        TestDBContext db = new TestDBContext();
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(TestModel test)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Name = test.Name;
                db.Emailid = test.Emailid;
                db.TestModels.Add(test);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            return RedirectToAction("review", "Test");


        }



        public ActionResult review(TestModel test)
        {
            TestModel testmodel = new TestModel();

           IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Drp_Names =db.TestModels.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Dataid.ToString(),
                Text = x.Emailid
            });
           ViewBag.Dataid = Drp_Names;
           return View(testmodel);

        }

    }
}
```

my model

```
public class TestModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Dataid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Emailid { get; set; }
        public int Flag { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Drp_Names { get; set; }
    }
    public class TestDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public TestDBContext()
            : base("TestDBContext")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<TestModel> TestModels { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int Dataid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Emailid { get; set; }
        public int Flag { get; set; }
    }
```

when i click on save i want to save the data and i want it take me to another view to show me the loaded drop down 
can any body help me out

Comment: what issue is coming in this code?

Comment: Can you please provide your View file name?

Comment: as the data is saving and it is not redirecting to second view

Comment: view file names 1.index 2.review

Comment: because your GET action is expecting a model but RedirectToAction does not pass models to it.

Comment: this is the error i am getting    LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: could u pls explain ...use my code

Comment: I think this is the line that is causing the error: `Value = x.Dataid.ToString(),`